# What is Scratch memory of a process?

Tags: memory, process, operating-system

I've seen the term "scratch memory" a few times, but i'm not sure what it means and i can't find a source to learn about it. I've seen it again on Wikipedia reading about Multics [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multics#Novel_ideas). Explanation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scratch memory?  Multics?   Are you doing an archaeology course?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Scratch memory" most likely refers to the [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) in the context you are talking about. I have heard it more in the context of computer architecture where it is a [small very fast memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratchpad_memory) that is used for things like interim values, it is related to a [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) but with less organization.